# I cannot get structure members in auto-completion or tooltips

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, emacs24

I want autocomplete or company to work with C code and I need structure context level autocomplete i.e if I have a struct:

```
typefdef struct HOST_ {

    IP4_ADDRESS     ip4;
    IP6_ADDRESS     ip6;
    MAC_ADDRESS     mac;    
} HOST;
```

... and then I have code:

```
HOST host;

host->
```

Then if I hit tab then I should get a drop down menu giving me all the (and only the) three options.

This is what I did:

```
(defun my-tab-del-commands(key-map)
  "This function sets the <tab> and <backspace> keymaps according to the special commands
that I have set. This needs to be set per mode keymap where it is needed. We cannot 
use the global keymap because that would override command completion in minibuffer"

  ;; Set TAB in  major-mode keymap to "tab-to-tab" stop
  ;; Use tab2tab stop and not just add +4 spaces (tab stop defined by tag-stop-list)
  (define-key key-map (kbd "<tab>")     'tab-to-tab-stop)

  ;; Define Key for <backtab>
  (define-key key-map (kbd "<S-tab>")   'backward-move-to-tab-stop)
  (define-key key-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'backward-move-to-tab-stop)

  ;; Define C-tab as my-indent-system 
  (define-key key-map (kbd "<C-tab>")   'my-indent-system)
  ;; Also provide a duplicate "\C-ci" in case C-TAB is overridden by any minor mode
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map "\C-ci"   'my-indent-system)

  ;; Shift backspace moves by one tab stop till no more whitespace
  (define-key key-map (kbd "<S-backspace>") 'backspace-whitespace-to-tab-stop)

  ;; Alt backspace is c-hungry-delete-backwards
  (define-key key-map (kbd "<M-backspace>") 'c-hungry-delete-backwards)
  )


;; Simple Backend of semantic with ede as project manager
;; Lets try semantic (CDET) backend for now only.
;; Later learn clang or rtags or other big stuff to handle the whole project
(defun backend:semantic-ede ()
  "Setup for semantic-mode with ede as project management. 
Simple stuff for starters"

  (semantic-mode 1)

  (global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)
  (global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
  (setq-mode-local c-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
                   '(project unloaded system recursive))
  (semantic-add-system-include my-lp-build-path)
  (semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode t)
  (semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode t)

  (require 'ede)
  (global-ede-mode)

  (let ((makefile (format "%s/Makefile" my-mp-source-path)))
    (when (file-exists-p makefile)
      (ede-cpp-root-project "openflow" :file makefile)))
  )


;; There are two "schools of thought" of intelligent autocomplete
;; (a) auto-complete package and (b) company package. 


;; This is auto-complete
(defun completion:auto-complete ()
  "Setup auto-complete with triggers. We still need to hook with C mode"

  ;; Then autocomplete
  (require 'auto-complete)
  (require 'auto-complete-config)
  (global-auto-complete-mode t)

  ;; auto complete mod
  ;; should be loaded after yasnippet so that they can work together

  (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
  (ac-config-default)

  (add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)

  ;; set the trigger key so that it can work together with yasnippet on tab key,
  ;; if the word exists in yasnippet, pressing tab will cause yasnippet to
  ;; activate, otherwise, auto-complete will
  (ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
  (ac-set-trigger-key "<tab>")  
  (global-auto-complete-mode t)

)

(defun my-smart-c-auto-complete()
  ;; Now tie up autocomplete with semantic
  ;; Later hook it up to c-mode-hook via c-mode-config func
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-dictionary)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-abbrev)

  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
)


;; This is company
(defun completion:company ()
    "Setup comany mode"
    (require 'company)
    (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
)

(defun tab-side-story ()
  (interactive)

  ;; First load and init Yasnippet - This sets the TAB first to Ysnippet
  ;; This will work on LISP & SHELL SCRIPTS also

  ;; (require 'yasnippet)
  ;; (yas-global-mode 1)

  ;; Second, use whatever completion mechanism you wanna use auto-complete or company
  ;; This will work on LISP also!
  ;;(completion:auto-complete)
  (completion:company)

  ;; Then this function sets tab command 
  (my-tab-del-commands c-mode-base-map)

)

;; Completion mechanism needs a backend
(backend:semantic-ede)
(tab-side-story)

;; define My Great C style with linux as the parent style (choose google if you wish)
(c-add-style "my-great-c-style"
             '("linux"              ; use linux as parent style
               (indent-tabs-mode . nil)     ; tabs are spaces
               (c-syntactic-indentation . t)    ; auto-syntax
               (c-syntactic-indentation-in-macros . t) ; ditto for macros
               (c-tab-always-indent . nil) ; Otherwise our complex TAB will not work!
               (tab-width   .  4)           ; if there is a <tab> expand to 4 spaces
               (backward-delete-function . nil)     ; DO NOT expand tabs when deleting
               (c-continued-statement-offset . 4))) ;continued statement offset 4


(defun my-c-mode-config ()
  (c-set-style "my-great-c-style")
  (when (= emacs-major-version 23)
    (gtags-mode 1))
   (when (= emacs-major-version 24)
    (tab-side-story)
    ;; (my-smart-c-auto-complete)
    (ggtags-mode 1)
    (setq ggtags-update-on-save nil))
  (electric-indent-mode)
  (setq c-basic-offset   4)
  (setq c-tab-always-indent nil))

;; Needs to be hooked - do it here instead of common area 
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-config)
```

Sorry for the very long code but most of them are my comments and notes jotted down so far less "code" than it seems. In this I have set it for company mode though I have auto-complete.

Both are not working! Something is clashing with something.

Comment: Can you run javascript on your programming?

Comment: No. Mostly C, ELISP, EXPECT and sometimes BASH & PERL